# Show values of a list?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have two beans with List and @ManyToMany annotation. Now I created a *JasperReports*'s report and I want to show values of lists.
I created the Field at report, after I added a Component List in my Detail Band and when I try display the report doesn't work.

Here how I am trying

```
@Entity
public class Conta

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany
   private List<PlanoDeConta> plano;


@Entity
public class PlanoDeConta{

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @NotNull @Column(unique=true)   
   private String planoConta;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="plano");
   private List<Conta> conta;
}
```

At *JasperReports*'s report I'm trying show values Field type List, for example: `plano.PlanoConta` but not works. I'm tried show values on Component List also.

I want show `planoConta` value.

How to I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in that situation was make a subreport and then put it in a group band, then in the properties of the subreport, one perhaps should make the

```
connection type = datasource by expression.
```

Then make

```
the datasource expression = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{plano}).
```

Then in my subreport i would have the fields: Id, planaConta, etc.

If you have any questions, just ask.